# Is there a way to assign zero to std::chrono::nanoseconds

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Is there a way to assign zero to a duration of type `std::chrono::nanoseconds`? I tried `duration::zero` but it failed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a [`zero()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/zero) function:

```
std::chrono::nanoseconds dur;
// ...
dur = std::chrono::nanoseconds::zero();
```

Or you could assign it to a temporary of type `nanoseconds` explicitly constructed with `0`:

```
dur = std::chrono::nanoseconds{0};
```

which is what `zero()` returns too.

Lastly, if you're using a compiler that supports it, there is just:

```
// requires either "using namespace std::chrono_literals;" or "using namespace std::chrono;"
dur = 0ns;
```